# How to create related field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, field, odoo-8

I am trying to create related field for displaying customer's balance in sale orders. I think i am creating wrong related field. Can anybody help me how to create related field in odoo?

**here this is related field i am creating**

`customer_balance = fields.Related('partner_id.credit', string='Customer Balance')`

**and other one is**

`customer_balance = fields.Char(related='partner_id.credit', store=True)`

Comment: its related to this, but i am using v8 api, and its for v7, and i am getting error also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. It will work for you.

```
customer_balance = fields.Float(related="partner_id.credit",string="Balance")
```

Thanks..

Comment: Okay, Let me check it again

Comment: yes i tried it, its giving same error as well, i don't know why this is happening. Related field code is right.

Comment: Okay, Wait i will check it now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/vagrant/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 152, in _dispatch
    rule, arguments = self._find_handler(return_rule=True)
  File "/vagrant/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 65, in _find_handler
    return self.routing_map().bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match(return_rule=return_rule)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1433, in match
    raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404: Not Found

Comment: customer_balance = fields.Float(related="partner_id.credit",string="Balance") This is work for me i think you got other issue.

Comment: automatically error removed, actually it was session destroyed error

Comment: but there is one thing, it is not displaying credit of customer, just 0.00 is showing.